# Combining two query results - php, mysql

Tags: php

So I'm doing something wrong (new to PHP) and I think the issue is related to my inexperience with manipulating arrays in php.

```
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM birds where breed = '".$row['breed']."' and wing_span = '".$row['wing_span']."' and id != '".$row['id']."' limit 4";
    $s_query = mysql_query($query2);

    $theArray = array();

    $counter = 0;
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($s_query)) {
        $counter = $counter + 1;
        array_push($theArray, $row3);
    }

    if($counter < 4) {
        $new_limit = 4 - $counter;

        $query5 = "SELECT * FROM birds where breed = '".$row['breed']."' and id != '".$row['id']."' limit ".$new_limit."";
        $s_query2 = mysql_query($query5);

        $counter = 0;
        while($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($s_query2)) {
            $counter = $counter + 1;
            array_push($theArray, $row5);
        }
    }
```

The goal is that if I don't reach the maximum of 4 in the first query, I will run a second query with the difference in MAX - count as the limit. But when I run that query, I try to add the rows ($s2_query) to the existing rows ($s_query)

In this attempt, I tried to create a new array, push the elements as I go. I've tried manually combining them too (array_merge), but also didn't work.

**Edit**
It's intentional for there to be two queries. Point is that if the first query doesn't give me a total of 4 results, I run a second query to fill the remaining spots.

Comment: What's not working? What is your output compared to your desired output?

Comment: I'll just leave this here... `(SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...) LIMIT 4;` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html

Comment: are you trying to order the results by the wing_span? I think you can simply add "ORDER BY wing_span DESC" and do everything with one only query

Comment: This is meant to be "show me 4 similar birds". So if the first result gives me less than 4, I then run a second, less specific query to fill the remaining spots. Order by not necessary.

Comment: I still find it an overkill. Look closely at the order by in the SQL reference. You can run this whole thing as one only query, first to list the specific result following by the less specific result, default, or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited answer [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) suggested a UNION in the comments which i think should work fine, try:

```
$query = "(SELECT *, 1 as SORY_QUERY1 FROM birds where breed = '".$row['breed']."' and wing_span = '".$row['wing_span']."' and id != '".$row['id']."') UNION (SELECT *, 2 FROM birds where breed = '".$row['breed']."' and id != '".$row['id']."') ORDER BY SORY_QUERY1 LIMIT 0, 4";

$theArray = mysql_fetch_array($s_query);

var_dump($theArray); //to debug
```

---

btw, you can just use

```
$theArray[] = $row5;
```

instead of

```
array_push($theArray, $row5);
```

Comment: Problem though - When I run the initial query, I get a multi-column result set. When I do a count on that array ($theArray), I'm getting 4. I should ONLY be getting two (two rows).

Comment: Also, that initial $theArray fetch generates a combination of the initial array with itself, so it's basically [hummingbird, hummingbird, 45, 45, 10.3, 10.3]

Comment: Thanks goes to you and decez for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As deceze said, only 1 request with UNION would best fit your needs.

Btw, use limit as a range

```
LIMIT 0, 4
```

Regards,